# How do you make an ideal circuit?

Tags: basic

I was reviewing for our class and I can't seem to understand how the book comes up with these answers.

[image: This was the circuit I have trouble analyzing]

Comment: To make an ideal circuit, you start with ideal parts...

Comment: How is the question in the title is related to the question in the body? And what is the actual one?

Comment: @KingDuken Nevertheless, when we analyze a circuit mathematically we must use a set of formally specified elements and these are called the ideal elements. That's what SPICE does. The fact that the universe does not contain ideal wires or ideal voltage sources does not mean that such analyses are not useful. The job of an engineer is to recognize which ideal elements are needed to create a useful **model** of a small part of the universe.

Comment: Start by asking yourself, what’s the value of \$i_b\$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to ans but give you hints to solve.

1. Observe the direction of 8A current source and ib.
2. Observe Vg source and 8A source, how they are connected in and its polarity.
3. Also the current dependent sorce (ib/4) wrt to Vg.
4. Calculate power using Power = V*I equation.

Hope this will help.